# SwaggerUI + NodeJs (Meteor)

Tags: node.js, rest, meteor, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a meteor app with a REST API by https://atmospherejs.com/simple/json-routes.

Now I want to document my API with SwaggerUI. I already used SwaggerUI in other projects and know you have to create a yaml or json sepc file, which then is being displayed by SwaggerUI.

So now I have discovered there are some existing swagger-ui packages for npm:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui
https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-dist

which I installed by `meteor npm install swagger-ui-dist --save-dev`

But I have no clue what to do next or how to use them.

I am sure it must be something as simple as:

```
const swaggerui = require('swagger-ui');
swaggerui.specPath(pathToYaml);
swaggerui.url('/api-docs');
```

Can anyone help me with the first steps?

Comment: Are you asking how to have those two npm packages (```meteor npm install --save <<package_name>>```) installed in meteor or are you asking how to configure swaggerui?

Comment: I have installed those packages but i don't understand how to use them. (i have used swaggerui before in another project but not in content with node nor as a npm package)

Comment: Something like this perhaps? ```Template.body.onRendered(function () {
  var swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
    url:"<<the-url",
    dom_id:"swagger-ui-container"
  });

  swaggerUi.load();
});```

Comment: @Gobliins: I'm at the very exact same place. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @RicardoPesciotta Unfortunately not :(